# Ajax call returning "Not Found" Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This SHOULD be very simple, but my ajax call is returning a "Not Found" error.  I've searched for similar issues, and tried the various suggestions, but to no avail.

## Front-end logic

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // ----------
        // Instant Quote Form
        // ----------
        $('.instant-form').submit(function() {
            $('.error').html('').hide();
            var var_url = $(this).attr('action');
            var var_data = $(this).serialize();
            var elem = this;
            var err = 0;
            var msg = '';

            alert("Driver Form Submitted: " + var_data);
            alert("Action: " + var_url);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: var_url,
                data: var_data,
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Returned : " + data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                    alert('FAILURE: status =' + status + ' error=' + error);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The Alert showing the URL is as follows:

> Action:
>   http://www.professionaldrivers.com/wp-content/themes/professionaldrivers/aqs/get-quote.php

If I enter the displayed URL in the browser, the php file is executed, so I know I have the correct path

Finally, I cut everything out of the PHP file for now.  So it only consists of:

### Back-end logic

```
<?php require('./../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');   
if(!isset($_POST['action']))
    die('horrible death');   
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
die();
?>
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possibly htaccess not allowing access to that path ?

Comment: The URL returns a 404, even if it displays the text, it has nothing to do with the JS ?

Comment: Have you checked if the var_data has the correct data and format?

Comment: Your webserver returns the HTTP error code 404 Not Found. Fix that first.

Comment: @charlietfl, I can click on the link above and get access to the path.. it will display "horrible death"

Comment: First, yes I check the data but I don't think incorrect data would generate a 404 error.  Second, I am looking for suggestions that would help fix the 404 error.  The URL http://www.professionaldrivers.com/wp-content/themes/professionaldrivers/aqs/get-quote.php does not get a 404 by itself so something else must be effecting it.

Answer (score -1):

This seems working , pasted the code in js fiddle http://jsfxxx.net/da4xyL1f/

Comment: Your link is broken... @Rajendra Kumar Vankada

Comment: replace jsfxxx with jsfiddle, as so doesnot direcly allow js fiddle links.